# Xamarin, не работает TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

Не могу понять почему не работает `TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PointViewCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}"` как будто что то перекрывает. Цепляю туда кнопку, кнопка кликает. Если выношу `TapGestureRecognizer` в первый `StackLayout`  после `ScrollView` то работает, но мне это не подходит так как там список и мне нужен клик на конкретную запись.

```
<ScrollView IsVisible="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" InputTransparent="True">
        <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding RouteListDoc.RowsRoute}" Padding="5">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame CornerRadius="5"  OutlineColor="#c3c3c3" BackgroundColor="#F2FFFFE0">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding PointViewCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" />
                                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large"/>
                                    <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Start.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="80">
                                    <Image Source="arrow.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="Пал:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Pal}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="КГ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Finish.KG}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="КМ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Start.KM}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                    <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пошел путем относительной привязки. Как оказалось нельзя биндить в списке от общей привязки, нужно либо делать обработчик непосредственно в экземпляре коллекции либо так как сделал я, как правильно не знаю.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

**Это шапка:**

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
       xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=dotMorten.Xamarin.Forms.AutoSuggestBox" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DriverHelper2.Behavior" 
       xmlns:view="clr-namespace:DriverHelper2.ViewModel"
       x:Class="DriverHelper_v_2._0.View.MainShell"
    Shell.BackgroundColor="White"
    Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor="White"
    Shell.ForegroundColor="Black"
    Shell.TabBarTitleColor="Black"
    Shell.TitleColor="Black"
    Shell.UnselectedColor="Gray"
    Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray"
    Shell.TabBarIsVisible="True"
    Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="Black"
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MainViewModel}"
       >
```

**Это выборка:**

```
<ScrollView IsVisible="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSetActiveRoute}" InputTransparent="True">
    <StackLayout  BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding RouteListDoc.RowsRoute}" Padding="5">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame CornerRadius="5"  OutlineColor="#c3c3c3" BackgroundColor="#F2FFFFE0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type view:MainShellViewModel}}, Path=PointViewCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" />
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Start.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large"/>
                                <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Start.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="80">
                                <Image Source="arrow.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label Text="Пал:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Pal}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label Text="КГ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Finish.KG}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label Text="КМ:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Start.KM}" FontSize="Medium" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="125">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Finish.RoutePoint}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" />
                                <Label Text="Вікно доставки:" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Finish.Windows}" FontSize="Medium" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```